# Python code runs fine in the terminal, but not when using the play button in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, open-telemetry, pylance

I have a project in a folder called "myproject" located in the "users/admin" directory on my Mac M1. In Visual Studio Code, I've created a workspace named "PROJECT" and placed the "myproject" folder inside it. This "myproject" folder has three subfolders: "f1","f2" and "f3"

To run my project, I use the "serve.py" file within the "f1" folder. I've also set up a Conda environment named 'alok' with all the necessary packages, and I'm using Python version 3.10.6.

Running "python serve.py" in the terminal and using the play button in Visual Studio Code both work fine. However, I want to debug my project using the 'debug python file' feature with the play/run button in Visual Studio Code. When I attempt to do this with "serve.py," I encounter an error:

```
File "/Users/admin/anaconda3/envs/alok/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 822, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I have tried changing the launch.json and settings.json files in .vscode to this configurations:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "python": "/Users/admin/anaconda3/envs/alok/bin/python"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "python.createEnvironment.contentButton": "show",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/admin/anaconda3/envs/alok/bin/python"
}
```

but still facing the error.